# Can't install java sdk, webupd8team repo gives sha256 errors and tar.gz from oracle gives broken output on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8, failed-installation

When attempting to install java from the linuxuprising/java or ppa:webupd8team/java i get an error like this

```
    Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:973d8ef6268da61e1003963186b8157207c6bc6e48d37d5e11fc2a5885a5b708
    - SHA1:28ede7da1dca520a59f4d7787511742c9b923084 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:7ba8544ff3e98f3c13d07a1803916781 [weak]
    - Filesize:78077648 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:ddb59fc787e254508a3cab0eec31bf0139b9510d83591e0f54a605e6a1f5615b
    - SHA1:1d78a279a988822b0c34312b284e73cd02103425 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:f44ade468641a9aea12a59539886c580 [weak]
    - Filesize:78077648 [weak]
```

I've tried installing from multiple version across both repos.  I've also tried installation oracle.com but when running tar -xzf jdk-version.tar.gz on the downloaded file i get an output like this, regardless of the jdk version i download from their site

```
$ sudo tar -xzf jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz 
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Archive contains ‘*\264\0\005*\264\0\a’ where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ‘I\003\0\001\0\032\0\030\0\001\0\023’ where numeric time_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ‘\207o\257\0\0\0\002’ where numeric uid_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ‘\024\0\0\0\006\0\001’ where numeric gid_t value expected
tar: *Y�: implausibly old time stamp 1969-12-31 18:59:59
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

It also generates an empty file called *Y� (invalid encoding)

I've very lost at this point, and would like to just get jdk working.  I feel like something is corrupted but how? why?